# Nextjs 14, best approach for a theme function that depends on cookies or query params

Tags: next.js, cookies, themes, next.js13

I have this function:

```
'use server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

import { initialTheme } from './initialTheme';
import { env } from '../env/server.mjs';

export const getTheme = async (slug?: string | undefined) => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const theme = cookieStore.get('theme')?.value;

  const themeSlug = slug || theme;

  let themeOptions = {} as Theme;

  themeOptions = await fetch(
    `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/themes/${themeSlug}`,
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ data }) => data);

  if (themeOptions) {
    Object.keys(themeOptions).forEach((key) => {
      const property = key as keyof typeof themeOptions;
      if (themeOptions[property] === '') delete themeOptions[property];
    });
  }

  themeOptions = { ...initialTheme, ...themeOptions };

  return { ...themeOptions, slug } as Theme;
};
```

that changes the theme of my web app. When it's used on server pages I can take the searchParams  (query params) and update the theme accordingly, if the searchParam is undefined it will get the cookie that is set on the middleware or the initialTheme. The problem is when I need to use it for example in a layout where we can not get the searchParams.

What I tried to do is to transform this function in client side and get the searchParams directly in the function using useSearchParams, although... I can't get the cookies as a fallback...

What I would like to do is to create a function with no arguments that takes the searchParams when applied or the cookie theme as fallback that can be used in client and server components.